# How to add WordPress shortcode into twitter bootstrap popover?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add contact form 7 shortcode like `<?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="10" title="Untitled"]' ); ?>` into bootstrap popover. Here is my popover code

```
data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-html="true"
data-content="<form role='form'>
<div class='form-group'>
    <input type='text' class='form-control' id='name' placeholder='Naam'>
</div>
<div class='form-group'>
    <input type='email' class='form-control' id='email' placeholder='Email'>
</div>
```

```
 <button type='submit' class='btn btn-default'>Send</button>

</form>" class="popover-link">Contact
```

I have replaced the `form` using that shortcode. But it is not working. Please tell me how can i do that?

Comment: If you are trying to add a contact form...perhaps a Bootstrap Modal would be easier for you to work with?

Comment: Contact form must popover when click on contact link